# How to update values not present in one array of objects from another array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays of objects which contain a huge amount of data.
The structure of these two arrays goes something like this.

```
arr1 = [
  {x: 1, y: '2018-01-01'}, 
  {x: 2, y: '2018-01-02'},           
  {x: 3, y: '2018-01-03'},
  {x: 5, y: '2018-01-05'},
....
]
```

```
arr2 = [
  {x: 1, y: '2018-01-01'}, 
  {x: 2, y: '2018-01-02'},           
  {x: 3, y: '2018-01-03'},
  {x: 4, y: '2018-01-04'},
  {x: 5, y: '2018-01-05'},
  {x: 6, y: '2018-01-08'}
]
```

I want to update `arr2` in such a way that it updates the array of objects with values that are only present in arr1 and drop any values not present in arr1. Note, I want to update the original arr2 and not return a new array.

I tried iterating through individual arrays and remove values not present but not luck.

Comment: please add your try and the wanted result. have both arrays the same order?

Comment: Are you matching the x value and updating the y value?

Comment: Try this - `arr2.splice(0, arr2.length, ...arr1);`

Comment: @NinaScholz, the arrays are sorted so the order shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @camaulay, no, the x values varies a lot so it shouldn't be matched imo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get a map and iterate from the end for splicing unknown items or update changed values.

```js
var arr1 = [{ x: 1, y: '2018-01-01x' }, { x: 2, y: '2018-01-02' }, { x: 3, y: '2018-01-03' }, { x: 5, y: '2018-01-05' }],
    arr2 = [{ x: 1, y: '2018-01-01' }, { x: 2, y: '2018-01-02' }, { x: 3, y: '2018-01-03' }, { x: 4, y: '2018-01-04' }, { x: 5, y: '2018-01-05' }, { x: 6, y: '2018-01-08' }],
    map = arr1.reduce((m, { x, y }) => m.set(x, y), new Map),
    i = arr2.length;

while (i--) {
    if (map.has(arr2[i].x)) {
        if (map.get(arr2[i].x) !== arr2[i].y) {
            arr2[i].y = map.get(arr2[i].x);
        }
    } else {
        arr2.splice(i, 1);
    }
}

console.log(arr2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Is there a way to have space separated key name in the reduce function?
`map = arr1.reduce((m, { "Two spaces", y }) => m.set("Two spaces", y), new Map)`

Throwing an error when i run it

Comment: you need another variable name: `map = arr1.reduce((m, { "Two spaces": key, y }) => m.set(key, y), new Map)`

Comment: What if the only check I want to do is the `y` column and no match between x column is required?

Comment: how should the result look like? (it looks like a different question.)

Comment: Pretty much same. I mean, return arr2 where column `y` matches but is not dependent on column `x`

Comment: then take it without `if (map.get(arr2[i].x) !== arr2[i].y) {`, but keep the assignment or not, depending what you want.